# Сумма ячеек без заливки

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Добрый день!
Возможно кто-то сможет подсказать скрипт для вычисления суммы ячеек без заливки цветом? 
Наткнула на вот такой скрип:

```
function sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
        x += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

И собственно на формулу к нему =sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("#ffffff", "B2:F13"). Вот только таблица ругается "Диапазон не найден (строка 3, файл Код)"
Буду признательна за любой совет =)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте что-то более стандартное, например

```
function sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var backgrounds = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgrounds();
    var values = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getValues();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++)
      for (var j = 0; j < backgrounds[0].length; j++)
        if (backgrounds[i][j] === color)
          sum += +values[i][j];
    return sum;
  } catch (err) {
    return err.message + ' ' + err.stack;
  }
}

function asNumber(v) {
  var res = Number(v);
  return isNaN(res) ? 0 : res;
}
```

Пример вызова

```
=sumWhereBackgroundColorIs("#ffffff"; "B2:F13"; B2:F13)
```

Пример Таблицы [Сумма ячеек без заливки [634197] #ruSO](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nQ5nVYEujZjvsTFTvwwZeZDLJrIBl-PKNzomK454Wyo/copy)

Comment: Это именно то, что нужно. Большое спасибо! А есть ли возможность добавить автообновление? Т.е. если сумма уже подсчитана и после этого закрашивается одна из ячеек. Чтобы сумма меняла автоматически =)

Comment: Если меняется число, обновление происходит. А вот при закрашивании нет =(

Comment: И не должно. Изменение цвета - это событие, накоторое можно подисаться через триггер, например, https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/099bc4194fd5973941a47d591518fe81 Вы же задавали впорос про пользовательскую функцию. Формально, я выдал верный ответ.

Comment: Да, все верно. Это был скорее дополнительный вопрос. Спасибо за ссылочку, буду разбираться =)

Comment: @Nastya, расчеты через такие штуки ненадежны.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли, только смог сделать по одному столбцу. По всему листу или по нескольким столбцам не считает. Подскажите, как расширить

Comment: @александр, создайте новый топик с кодом и описанием проблемы

Comment: @Nastya, можно пометить вопрос как решенный.